# How to get the user Record using the google-cloud firestore auth by getUserByPhoneNumber?

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise, firebase-admin

I have to extract data from the user using auth by phone Number.
I have an array of user's phone number.

I have written a solution and it gives the required output but it doesn't terminate. How can I solve this problem?

"phoneNumberArray" is the array of user's phone number. It is mostly related to HTTP background trigger functions.I have solved this but this is a firebase issue so please see this

```js
const user = async () => {
    const getAuth = async phoneNumber => {
        return auth.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber).catch(() => {
            return {
                phoneNumber,
                uid: null,
                email: '',
                displayName: '',
                emailVerified: false,
                disabled: false,
            };
        });
    };

    const userRecord = await Promise.all(
        phoneNumberArray.map(phoneNumber => {
            return getAuth(phoneNumber);
        }),
    );
    //when i console.log(userRecord) it's print the output
    const x = {
        'userRecord Length': userRecord.length
    }
    console.log(x)
    return;
}
   module.exports = {user}
```

Comment: `but it doesn't terminate` - what doesn't terminate? does the function you've posted get to the console.log? if so, then the function is done - perhaps you're calling it wrong

Comment: by the way `phoneNumberArray.map(phoneNumber => {
                return getAuth(phoneNumber);
            })` is more simply written like `phoneNumberArray.map(getAuth)`

Comment: @JaromandaX when i run node filename than it wouldn't close and it prints the output and if i remove this code then it will terminate and i have also used your suggestion but still getting the same problem

Comment: @JaromandaX can you please let me know what am I calling wrong?

Comment: So, your code outputs the result of `console.log(x)` but then does not terminate, and, if you remove this code, then the code does terminate - this is what I understand from your comment. So, how do you call the function you've presented in the question?

Comment: @JaromandaX i have called this file in other file and i have module the function and called in this way.
const user = require('./filename.js')
user();

Answer (score 1):

I have used this way to solve the function.

```
in the main file i have to return 
return x,admin;
and the calling file works like this
const {user} = require('./filename');
user().then(e => {
console.log(e.x)
e.admin.apps[0].delete();
})catch(error){
console.log(error)}
```